# Set the value of an attribute of my component with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I have a react-native app and I use Jest for my unit tests.

Just to illustrate what I am asking, here is a simplified version of my component :

```
class GuidePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.name = '';
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.name);
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to set the value of `this.name` during my test?

Comment: What do you use for rendering in your test.

Comment: If you want a valid test, you should probably set `this.name` using whatever function it normally uses to set the value

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I use `react-test-renderer`
@GarrettMcCullough Is there a way I could call a method of my component?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp You should be able to do something like `GuidePicker.instance().method()` to call a method of your component